# Get a reference to a class to output meta information of calling class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, metaprogramming

I am debugging some callbacks in our ActiveRecord models. I'd like to have a globally available method like the following:

```
logger.info("at end of ITEM calling check_status")
```

but I'd like to have a generic version that I could add to any model class. I was thinking of monkey patching ActiveRecord::Base like the following in initializers/my_initializer.rb:

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
  # this worked
  def end_log_proof
    logger.info("this should work")
  end


  def end_log(klass)
    logger.info("at end of ( #{klass.name} )")
    logger.info("calling #{klass.__method__}.upcase at file #{klass.__FILE__} line: #{klass.__LINE__}")
  end
end
```

and if I call like this:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save :my_callback

  def my_callback
    end_log_proof # this works
    end_log(self) # ouptuts : "calling MY_CALLBACK at ...."
  end
```

The second one fails with:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `name' for #<Item:0x007feab6359e38>):
```

I am trying to get a reference to the calling context - how would I get this to work?

Comment: I think it should be `end_log(self.class)`

Comment: Actually, instead of passing `klass` you can simply call `self.class.name` in place of `klass.name`

Comment: thx - that works for the name but is there a way to get the reference to the calling method and __FILE__ and __LINE__ references for the calling function?